# Aviationstack API Error: HTTPS Encryption Not Supported

Tags: javascript, http, https

After having tested my API key and making sure it works, I tried calling the Aviationstack API, I would get this JSON:

`{"error":{"code":"https_access_restricted","message":"Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption."}}`

In my app, the link pointing to the API is an HTTP link, but upon having visited the link directly, it would do the same thing. Is there any possible way to prevent this from happening?

Thank you in advance.

I didn't try anything out of the ordinary

Comment: Are there any messages on the console?  I know Firefox automatically upgrades HTTP to HTTPS requests if you enable HTTPS-Only Mode in security settings.

Comment: I made sure to disable HTTPS-only mode on every browser I used. I tried on Chrome, Firefox and Brave; all of which yield the same result. As far as console messages, it’s only the message from the API saying “my subscription doesn’t support HTTPS encryption”

Comment: I even tried running the test requests in the documentation [here](https://aviationstack.com/documentation), and even the API call in their documentation does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up in the same error while trying to fetch some data from the Aviation-stack API using my "Free" plan Access_Key.

`` axios.get(`http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=${ACCESS_KEY}&flight_date=2023-07-18`) ``

```
{
   "code": "https_access_restricted",
   "message": "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not 
               support HTTPS Encryption."
},
```

Then i gave it another try on [postman](https://www.postman.com/) but this time removing the param(`flight_date=2023-07-18`)

`http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=my_access_key_goes_here`
and surprisingly it send me back Data for 100 flights(100 is the maximum limit for the free plan).

Therefore the above error should be related to the fact that modern browser(Chrome in my case) redirects all 'http' requests into 'https' if you had previously made the same request from the browser- you may check this out by opening your network tab on your browser while making the API request using the URL provide on the DOCS( you will see something like this `status 307 Internal Redirect (from disk cache)`).

Therefore, i recommend that you make the  API call using only 'HTTP' from your local code base or any other API platforms like POSTMAN.

Note:One more thing i have noticed though

You can not make API call to the `routes` endpoint as well as you can not pass params to the `flights` endpoint(ex. passing flight_date param or the `search` param for [auto-complete](https://aviationstack.com/documentation#autocomplete) )
if you try to pass a param to the flights endpoint or you try to fetch data from the `routes` endpoint
it throws back a different error.

```
{
   "error": {
     "code": "function_access_restricted",
     "message": "Your current subscription plan does not support this API 
        function."
    }
 }
```

Conclusion: the aviation-stack free plan is useful to make api calls- only to some endpoints (ex. flights,airports,airlines) without any additional params.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your subscription must be a free plan that HTTPS connection is not supported.
[Aviationstack API Pricing][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiA2i.png 
As you see you need to pay for at least basic subscription to have the HTTPS encryption.

The browser is blocking your website to load the data from HTTP because an encrypted website having some unencrypted communication with other web server is violating the means of encryption.

So you have 3 options to do: 
 1. Pay for the subscription (thats all the api company wants you to do)
 2. Set your web app protocol as HTTP port 80 only, or visit your web server with http. (Make sure your DNS server doesnt automatically change your connection from port 80 HTTP to port 443 HTTPS) 
For individual use but still wanted to connect the web app to the internet, this method works but it scores bad in SEO (Search Engine Optimization) 
 3. Use localhost/ 127.0.0.1 to run the web app (basically Live Server in VS Code) By default, the localhost should use HTTP, because there is no certificate sign to your localhost. This is for educational use or testing as the web app is not connected to the server.

I havent try this flight API before so I dont have a recommendation. But by searching directly from Google, this API provider states that you would have some request limitation, but should work fine with HTTPS. More detail please look at the website below.
https://developers.amadeus.com/pricing#pricing-list

Besides, just a small advice for some web developers calling APIs or other link sources with HTTP but hosting the web as HTTPS, there is a meta tag to automatically upgrade all HTTP connection to HTTPS.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Hope this helps you.